# Totals in SQL Pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I would like to get spreadsheet like to totals to this SQL Pivot I have. Below works fine to display the values in pivot format without subtotals. If there is a way to get both row & column total's that would be great. If not, at least total at the bottom would be fine.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT period, status
          FROM tasks )
 PIVOT
 (
  COUNT(status)
    FOR status IN ('Completed' AS "Completed", 
                   'WIP' AS "WIP",
                   'Not Started' AS "Not Started")
 )
ORDER BY period
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `PIVOT`, you can use `ROLLUP` and conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT CASE GROUPING_ID(period) WHEN 1 THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE TO_CHAR(period) END AS period,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Completed'   THEN 1 END) AS completed,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'WIP'         THEN 1 END) AS wip,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Not Started' THEN 1 END) AS not_started,
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   tasks
GROUP BY ROLLUP(period)
ORDER BY period;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tasks (period, status) AS
SELECT 1, 'Completed'   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'WIP'         FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Not Started' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Completed'   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'WIP'         FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Completed'   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Not Started' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;
```

Outputs:

> | PERIOD | COMPLETED | WIP | NOT_STARTED | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 6 |
> | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
> | 3 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 6 |
> | TOTAL | 9 | 3 | 3 | 15 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=11a8b8fc839d66ae52b0a05901e2b81e)*

Comment: How can I get the same values in % of the total? For ex - for period 1 - Completed column should show 50% instead of 3

Comment: @VamC Divide the value by the total and multiply by 100; same as calculating any other percentage.